# when will the responder flow gets call in the Initiator flow?

Tags: corda

I am just confused when the responder flow gets executed in flow class and that responder checks and signing the transcation?

Comment: just when you call CollectSignaturesFlow (withRequisiteSignature,otherPartySession) in the sub-flow. Yes, it checks.

Comment: is then how you feed input to responder?what is the exact input?

Comment: your signature already has all the input i.e. the transaction details

Comment: ok @Kid101 Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of flow annotations:

- `InitiatingFlow`, which is used to annotate flows that are started directly (either by other flows, by a service, or via RPC)
- `InitiatedBy`, which is used to annotate flows that the node starts in response to messages from other flows. This annotation takes as its only argument the name of an `InitiatingFlow` class

When a node receives a message from a flow running on another node, it goes through the following process:

- It checks whether it has a flow installed that is `InitiatedBy` the flow it has a received a message from

  - If it does, it invokes that flow to commence communication with the `InitiatingFlow`
  - If it does not, it throws an exception

So a responder flow instance gets created every time the node receives a message from the responder flow's `InitiatedBy` flow. This flow "stays alive" until it has finished communicating with the `InitiatedBy` flow instance.